# Is this a allyl bromide? If not what is it?

Tags: organic-chemistry

This molecule should be a allyl bromide:
[image: allyl bromide]

but what about this one:
[image: unknown]

What is it?

Comment: 2-Bromopropene?

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly mentioned,  [image]

is [allyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allyl_group) bromide.

**It's IUPAC name is 3-BromoProp-1-ene.**

---

[image]

**The IUPAC name of this compound is 2-BromoProp-1-ene.**
It is a homologue of ***[Vinyl Bromide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinyl_bromide)***.

---